# is it possible to reverse xxd to get original file from binary file

Tags: linux, command-line, binary-files, xxd

i have been using `xxd` to create a hexa representation of a file(any file like .jpg, .docx, .zip etc), like this,..

```
$ xxd -p original_file.zip > hexa_format.txt
```

and to reverse

```
$ xxd -r -p hexa_format.txt > original_file.zip
```

if anybody feels that this isn't the proper way, please correct me. 
anyhow this isn't my question.
now i have to convert them to binary instead of hexa. so the command goes like this, if im correct.

```
$ xxd -p -b original_file.zip > binary_format.txt
```

**my question is**,
how do i reverse it back to the original file from the binary file(binary_format.txt) created from the above command. the man page of xxd says it cannot be done(in the last line).

```
-b | -bits
              Switch to bits (binary digits) dump, rather than hexdump.   This
              option  writes octets as eight digits "1"s and "0"s instead of a
              normal hexadecimal dump. Each line is preceded by a line  number
              in  hexadecimal and followed by an ascii (or ebcdic) representa‐
              tion. The command line switches -r, -p, -i do not work with this
              mode.
```

if this couldn't be done is there any other command that can do it,. like piping multiple comamnds so.

Comment: `xxd` does not output binary files. It outputs textual representations of files. Please read the manual page. The binary format mentioned above is just the bytes of the file written out in 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own binary to hex function ...

```
cut -f2-8 -d' ' infile | tr -d '\n' | tr ' ' '\n' | while read l; 
do 
  echo -n    $(bin_to_hex($l)) >> outfile
  (( ++n )) 
  (( n % 60 == 0)) && echo  "" >> outfile 
done
```

This should output the same format as `-p` which can then be run through `-r`.
If you read the man page for `xxd` you will read that there is no `-r` for `-b`. It says so on the excerpt that you included in your question.

Comment: Should i place these lines inside a file and then run it as a `.sh`,..?

Comment: This will not recover the exact text. It just add enter on each 60th symbol!

Comment: You can put it in a file or on the command line. This will output the same format as `-p`: 60 hex values per line.

Comment: I see, so you rewrite the coder

Comment: Terminal says  
bash: command substitution: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `$l'  

bash: command substitution: line 18: `bin_to_hex($l))'

Comment: You have to write your own function `bin_to_hex()`. You do understand that xxd outputs TEXTUAL representations of files, right?

Answer (score 0):

You alter the structure of the file do you can't easy do this. Maybe something like this can help (but you will loose newline characters:

```
awk '{printf $8}' binary_format.txt >out_file
```

Comment: terminal troughs back this:  
`awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf("...%&'")
 FILENAME="bin_jpg.txt" FNR=59 NR=59.`    

My usage is more or less like recovering the original file,

Comment: try to exec it on this way: awk '{printf "%s" $8}' binary_format.txt >out_file

Comment: now the error is, `awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf("%s......")
 FILENAME="bin_jpg.txt" FNR=1 NR=1`.

Comment: '{printf "%s",$8}' And update your version of awk, seems your is very old

Comment: Why would you be interested only in the eighth field?

Comment: @Allen, check please how the format (binary) looks like. The original content is in field 8. The rest is counter and binary strings

Comment: @R. Ninov: Wrong. That is a textual representation that is not one to one. It uses a period, '.', for anything that doesn't have an ASCII printable character.

Comment: @Allen, didn't check that, just test with ascii file

Comment: @Allen, im suppose push 2 different files into another program(i know this sounds lame,.). This particular program accepts only binary representation/format of any file(it doesn't accepts .jpg, .zip etc) that's been given as input. That's the reason i need to convert them into binary. im not an expert, but since i came across with this `xxd` that can get binary format of a file, i chose this way.

Comment: In unix, a file is just a stream of bytes. What program are you talking about?

Comment: xxd takes a file that is a 'binary' format and outputs a TEXTUAL representation of it so it is not what you want anyway.

Comment: @Allen, its just a code written in python, which doesn't have much file handling techniques like buffers or stringIO modules.(nothing huge or impressive about that program/code). so if you think this is not what im suppose to do, you have any suggestions.